# Delete Special Characters From File- Unix

Tags: linux, unix, command-line, scripting

I have a file that is supposed to be formatted like this:

```
   ID     QTY 
xxxxxxxxx,xxx 
xxxxxxxxx,xxx 
xxxxxxxxx,xxx 
xxxxxxxxx,xxx 
xxxxxxxxx,xxx
```

Sometimes comes formatted like this though with the special characters separating the first 9 digits.

```
xxx,xx,xx,xx,xxx
xxx/xx/xx/xx,xxx
xx.xxx.xxxx,xxx
```

I would like to know how to delete any special characters from the entire ID.

Comment: I have `sed -e 's/[;,()'\'']/ /g;s/  */ /g' $newDir/$processNew > tmp && mv -f tmp $newDir/$processNew`but that takes out the "," in between the ID and QTY and I need to keep that one.

Comment: Does the last column always consists of three characters?

Comment: Not necessarily. There's a script that boots after my script and I believe it reads left of the comma and right of the comma.

Comment: Does the first column always consists of 9 characters?

Comment: It should always be 9 characters after the special characters are all deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Can be useful. If both the fields length is fixed i.e. 9 and 3 characters then use this.

```
sed  's/[\/.\,]//g' test2|awk '{print substr ($0, 1,9)","substr ($0, 10,13)}'
```

If only first field length is fix i.e. 9 characters then use this command.

```
sed  's/[\/.\,]//g' test2|sed -r -e 's/^.{9}/&,/'
```

Comment: On a rare occasion, the ID will start with a smaller number and wont fill the whole 9 digits. I have got that under control, but making the code work together is a pain. Is there a way I can use the last comma as the midpoint and delete any special characters left of that comma?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sed script. It removes *every* special character and then reinserts the `,`  after the ninth on lines containing special characters:

```
sed -r '/[./,]/ {s/[,/.]//g; s/(.{9})(.*)/\1,\2/g}'
```

Comment: Is there anyway to leave that comma there without having to add it back in? Sometimes the first 9 digits needs a leading zero and that would mess that test case up.